# Select one row from B where matches A?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working on getting a query to work that will convert an id type name to a user friendly name. I have two tables I'm attempting to query, `A = ID` `B = User Friendly Names`. I'm running the following query which is not working but is supposed to select the `actual_name` from `Table B` where Table B's app_id is equal to Table A's app_id.

```
SELECT A.user_dim.app_info.app_id, S.actual_name
FROM `hidden.app_events_20170116` A
LEFT JOIN `hidden` S ON A.user_dim.app_info.app_id = S.app_name
LIMIT 1
```

Essentially, select `tableb.actual_name` where `tablea.app_id` equals `tableb.app_id`

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Joining on `app_id = app_name` is highly suspicious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is Bigquery sql.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "Not working" means that the `actual_name` column is returning `null`

Comment: assuming you've adopted gordon's change, and given you're limiting to 1 row, have you checked that the app_id in the first row returned definitely has a matching row containing a value for actual_name in the original table? It's a left join, so it's perfectly possible to return a row from table a where there's no match against table b.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, I was matching on something that didn't exist.

Comment: @JoeScotto - somehow I really doubt below answer anyhow works in BigQuery! Does it really work for you? just curious

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I had to change the column names to the correct ones but it does work correctly but wasn't what I wanted in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `join` is on the wrong column:

```
SELECT ae.user_dim.app_info.app_id, h.actual_name
FROM `hidden.app_events_20170116` ae LEFT JOIN
     `hidden` h
     ON ae.user_dim.app_info.app_id = h.app_id;
```

Comment: Still returning `null` for `actual_name`

Comment: Consider an inner join rather than an outer join.